# how to invoke dependent rest services

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am building rest services using rest easy. There are two resources - student and course and a 1:N relationship between student and course.
To get the student details : Url will be /students/1
To get the course details : /students/1/courses/science.

Source code :

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Course> courses;

}

public class Course {

    private String name;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

}

@Path("/students")
public class StudentService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getStudentDetails(@PathParam("id") int studentId) {

        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(200);
        //Just sending back the id for now
        return builder.entity(studentId+"").build();

    }

}

@Path("/students/{id}/courses")
public class CourseService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getCourseDetails(@PathParam("name") String courseName) {

        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(200);
        //Just sending back the name for now.
        return builder.entity(courseName).build();

    }

}
```

The code works fine, but the path for CourseService does not look right. Is there any redirect that could be called from StudentService?
Also, is there an option in REST, to retrieve only the name of the student rather than the entire object?

Comment: Please show your code: what have you tried? Where did it go wrong? What could you get to work? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am sorry for the way i asked the question. Edited with the sample source code.  The code works fine, but the path for the CourseService is what worries me. Is that the right way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should distinguish the two services/resources.
To get student detail use: */students/{id}*
To get course detail use: */courses/{name}*

```
@Path("/courses")
public class CourseRes {

    @Inject 
    CourseService myCourseService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{courseName}")
    public Course get(@PathParam(value="courseName") String courseName){
        Course course = myCourseService.getCourse(courseName);
        return course;
    }
}


@Path("/students")
public class StudentRes {

    @Inject 
    StudentService myStudentService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{studentId}")
    public Student get(@PathParam(value="studentId") String studentId){
        Student student = myStudentService.getStudent(studentId);
        return student;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{studentId}/courses")
    public List<Course> get(@PathParam(value="studentId") String studentId){
        List<Course> courses = myStudentService.getCourseByStudentId(studentId);
        return courses;
    }

}
```

Retrieve only the name of the student rather than the entire object is not a best practice.
Anyway the object provided by the StudentService could be enhanced only with the name. It depends on your
inner implementation.

**UPDATE:**

For dependent services with multi-level hierarchy like *@Path("/{studentId}/courses/{coursename}/x/{xname]/y/{yname}")* you can use [ResourceContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html) to initialize the sub-resource instance with the ids in the path.

But you must be aware that these sub-resources depend on the parent.

```
@Path("/students")
public class StudentRes {

    @Path("{studentId}/courses") 
    public CourseStudentRes getCourseStudentRes(
         @PathParam("studentId") int studentId,
         @Context ResourceContext rc) {
        return rc.initResource(new CourseStudentRes(studentId));
    }
}

@RequestScoped
@Produces("application/json")
public class CourseStudentRes {

    private int studentId;

    public CourseStudentRes(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Path("{courseName}/x") 
    public XCourseStudent getXCourseStudentRes(
         @PathParam("courseName") String courseName,
         @Context ResourceContext rc) {
        return rc.initResource(new XCourseStudent(studentId,courseName));
    }


@RequestScoped
@Produces("application/json")
public class XCourseStudentRes {

    private int studentId;
    private String courseName;

    public XCourseStudentRes(int studentId, String courseName) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    @Path("{xName}/y") 
    public YXCourseStudentRes getYXCourseStudentRes(
         @PathParam("xName") String xName,
         @Context ResourceContext rc) {
        return rc.initResource(new YXCourseStudentRes(studentId,courseName,xName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure.I would distinguish the services.
For dependent services with multi-level hierarchy like @Path("/{studentId}/courses/{coursename}/x/{xname]/y/{yname}"), all those methods have to be defined in the parent service right? Makes the code clumsy.

Comment: Or should there be a limit to the hierarchy level?

Comment: Yes, you can implement dependent services. I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: I don't think there is a limit to the number of sub-resources you can have. However if the hierarchy becomes too long you have to wonder if the service is well designed